# If PUB starts first and connects to XPUB/XSUB proxy, messages get dropped till the time SUB is not connected

Tags: c++, message-queue, zeromq

I have implemented a ZeroMQ-based infrastructure to pass messages from multiple `PUB`-s to multiple `SUB`-s, using `XPUB/XSUB`-proxy in c++.

Multiple `PUB`(s) --> `XSUB/XPUB` proxy--> multipe `SUB`(s)

If I start all the `SUB`(s) and then start the `PUB`(s) then it is working as per design, but if I start the `PUB`(s) first and then I start the `SUB`(s), then all the messages from `PUB`(s) in between this time are dropped.

**Is there a work around for this?**

Since in the application it may happen that a `SUB` gets closed or crashes, so messages from any `PUB` for that `SUB` should not be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

### This is well a know feature. ZeroMQ design knowingly works this way.

In case you try to circumvent this, best to start with re-reading the ZeroMQ design maxims, one of which is a ZeroWarranty principle.

The best next step is to visit the **great and insightful book** from Pieter HINTJENS, available also in pdf, "**Code Connected: Volume 1**".

There are both the principles and design-workarounds discussed, so worth spend your time and efforts to read the whole story and understand both the design-reasons and technical options that may help you further in professional [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) design.